# Deployment Error caused by duplicate label

Tags: deployment, metadata, salesforcedx, deployment-api

at the moment I'm working on a project where Salesforce DX is used.
There I have a problem when I try to add the item "Messe" to the Opportunity LeadSource picklist.

```
<standardValue>
    <fullName>Convention</fullName>
    <default>false</default>
    <label>Messe</label>
</standardValue>
```

I can add this without any problems on my Scratch Org and also can pull the changes. But if I try to push it to a new Scratch I receive the following error:

```
force-app/main/default/standardValueSets/LeadSource.standardValueSet-meta.xml                       
Duplicate label: Messe
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through this article, it seems related to your issue : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Metadata-deploy-to-reactivate-deleted-picklist-values&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse. Unfortunately the arcticle couldnt´'t help me with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to deploy a picklist with a label that is either already deployed in the environment or is being loaded in the same deploy.

Since its just a label and not the Api name of the value, you may think that there is no problem if you repeat it, but Salesforce doesnt let you duplicate neither the Api value nor the label.

You will need to change the label -maybe something like "Messe." could work for you, but it looks a little dirty- or use the other picklist value.

Comment: It got it working by manually adding a blank behind "Messe". Now it looks like this: "Messe ". It is not the perfect solution, but for the moment it will work. Hopefully we can bypass this error with package installs.

Thanks for you advice.

Comment: @PhilippConrad this is a weird workaround but it works.

Comment: I see so after you deploy you can delete the dirty label?